# How to automatically download the files that have a download button on a webpage without BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, url, python-requests

I have created a streamlit app that has a download button to download a csv file. I want to automatically download the content using "GET" or "POST" requests. is there anyway to do that?

Here is my app URL:
https://maalaei97-test2.hf.space/?__theme=light

I tried to use urllib2.Request("GET", URL) but I receive None. I should mention that since I use the python script inside a software which only supports Iron Python, I do not have access to libraries like Beautifulsoap and requests. But I have access to urllib2 and webbrowser libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked your website, it uses the JavaScript on that button to open a new window and download your CSV. The actual URL in your case is:

```
https://maalaei97-test2.hf.space/media/c721b14394345aab14989004e9ce8a3bae6fbb02a8e8d6a41a4f5401.csv?title=app%20%C2%B7%20Streamlit
```

I think you can download this with `urllib` and `GET` request. If you want to click on that link with python, you need to run JavaScript code.

Comment: I used the actual URL and managed to download the file using urllib and GET. but what if I want to upload a file in a similar way? How can I find the actual URL of an upload button? For instance here is the link to an app that receives a CSV file and outputs another one: https://maalaei97-test3.hf.space/?__theme=light

Comment: You need to check the website with the developers dashboard of your browser to see which URLs and how it calls them